# what does "in quiet sophistication" mean here?

Tags: meaning, expressions, prepositions

"it strikes me as the last word in quiet sophistication."

I have two questions here.

First, I do not understand the meaning of "quiet sophistication." I know that sophistication is a trait regarding being smart, articulate, sensible, and sensitive. But I do not know how this trait can be quiet. So, I do not understand the noun phrase "quiet sophistication" altogether.

Second, I do not understand what is the function of "in" in the "in quiet sophistication." As I said above, sophistication is a kind of trait. Then, I do not understand how "the last word" could be "in" the "quiet sophistication" and I do not know the meaning also. Help me

Comment: Have you looked up the definition of *quiet*? If you have, have you found any meaning that can be consistent with sophistication? Is a *quiet child* the same as a *quiet color*? In the phrase, *the latest in mens' fashion*, what does *in* mean?

Comment: Yeh..I have. I kind of understand what "quiet sophistication" means. But I do not understand the meaning of the whole sentence, linking "the last word", "in", and "quiet sophistication"

Comment: Please don't be too harsh on me.. I am just dumb and persistent. ...

Comment: I'm not being hard on you. Policy here is that people should *show their work* (even if they often do not). Please show us possibilities. Also, consider the questions in the above comment.

Comment: @Huidong: It may help you to contrast your "quiet" with the way people refer to, for example, [**loud clothes**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22loud+clothes%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl). Essentially, it's about whether the appearance of something would rate as either a 0 or a 10 (*not at all*, or *extremely*) when judged in terms of how *ostentatious, gaudy, noticeable* it is.

Comment: In this case I believe "quiet" means subtle.

Answer (score 1):

I think the trouble you're having here is with the idiom "the last word in," which means something along the lines of "the epitome of" or "the authority on." I would understand your phrase to mean that "it" embodies subtle sophistication in the opinion of the speaker. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

'Quiet' in this sense means 'unobtrusive' or 'inconspicuous'. It's a sophistication that is understated...it does not call attention to itself. You may have met persons who display urbanity, knowledge, humor and an easy-going manner and do it effortlessly without any air of superiority or snobbishness. These people are rare, indeed. But they exist. It all boils down to one word--'charm'.